# Clojure: Combining a vector of univariate functions with a vector of arguments

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

If I have two vectors [1 2 3] [4 5 6] I can "zip" them together in clojure by

```
(map vector [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
```

to get ([1 4] [2 5] [3 6])

If I have a vector of univariate functions [f g h] and a vector of arguments, say, integers [1 2 3] what is the operation that I am looking for that will output ((f 1) (g 2) (h 3))? I think this must be a common operation but I don't know what the name is.

I guess I could do something like

(map (fn [f x] (f x)) [f g h] [1 2 3])

Comment: That would be `(map 'list #'funcall fns args)` in CL, but Clojure has only `apply`, which requires argument lists. Your anonymous function is fine.

Comment: You could do `(map #(%1 %2) funs values)` but I don't think there's a built-in 'application' function.

Comment: This is not a common operation in Clojure. I think Lee's suggestion is the best solution.

Comment: just for fun: `(map apply [+ - *] [1 2 3] (repeat nil))` you have to use additional sequence, because the last arg of the `apply` should be sequable